# how to recover vs code unsaved deleted file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created a file with no title in vs code but suddenly closed the file without saving changes. Is there any way to recover it I tried the `.config/code/backup` folder but did not find the file?

Comment: most likely it was not a 1000+ lines piece of text, let it be a lesson to save and use an SCM

Comment: @rioV8 of course it was not that many lines but it was important anyway thanks.

Comment: see also [Visual Studio Code unsaved files location](https://superuser.com/q/1225368/1749748)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have faced the issue when my computer was hanged. If you are mac user then this might helpful to you. We need to find the where the backup folder exist. This generally exist `~/Library/Application Support/Code/Backup` your file data will here.
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am not using Mac.

Comment: For transparency, the equivalent path on Windows would be `%APPDATA%\Code\User\Backups`.

Comment: %APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\Backups